# Nether Portal never goes to Nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a FTB Unleashed server, which I'm in the process of setting up before going public.  Part of that setup is checking the Nether etc. So I built a Nether portal and strangely all it does is pass me around Nether Portals in the Overworld.

What have I done wrong?

The DIM1 folder is missing - so I suspect some generation is supposed to happen?

Comment: Have you installed any additional mods? Using any alternate servers (MCPC for example)? Installed stuff like TickThreading?

Comment: @Macha I haven't installed any other servers. I have just installed Multiverse though to see if that can solve the problem. So far, same problem. If I destroy the second portal, it rebuilds itself. Very clever I thought. Still no Nether though.

Comment: Is the Nether disabled in your system settings?

Comment: I believe it was dim-1 that is the nether, and dim1 is the end

Comment: @Nether how can I check that?  With Multiverse installed, I am able to visit the nether - but not through a portal in the Overworld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server.properties make sure Nether is enabled

Comment: Thanks @YoltsJoe, I feel like a complete plank - but this is what it was. Always keep it simple! ;)

Answer (score -1):

DIM1 Folder is just for Nether Reseting. Deleting the DIM1 File just resets the Nether back to its original form when you first spawned. Check if your server.propeties file Nether is enabled.